# How do I add a sequence of numbers to a file

Tags: time, seq

Ok what I'm trying to do is time how long it takes to write a sequence of numbers to a file,
what I have so far is

time seq 12 2 900

how do I get this number sequence to write to a file?

Ta.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `> file` at the end of the command.

Comment: I have tried this, it only writes the first number to the file.

Comment: Awesome! worked perfectly..  thank you

Comment: If it works for you!  Upvoted.

Comment: Also, if you only want to APPEND to a file you can do it with a double carat, like this:  ` >> file `